# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a F2FS partition

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, system-installation, gparted, f2fs

How can I install Ubuntu 14.04 on a F2FS partition? I created the partition with Gparted but during the installation the Ubuntu installer could not recognize the filesystem on the partition. I heard it is possible to install with the alternative DVD but they say it is only available for Lubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

F2FS is not officially supported bu Ubuntu ([bug #1261175](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1261175)) but it should work if you do a normal install, then update initrd to include the f2fs module, copy the root filesystem to a f2fs format partition, re-install grub, and reboot.

Something like (warning: untested):

```
Create 3 partitions: /boot=ext2 /=ext4 f2fs
Install Ubuntu /boot=ext2 /=ext4, grub on sda
Boot from hard drive
add f2fs to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs
Boot from CD
mount ext4 / on /mnt/ext4
mount f2fs on /mnt/f2fs
cp -a /mnt/ext4/ /mnt/f2fs/
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/fsf2/boot
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/fsf2
poweroff, remove CD, turn on
```

Comment: Looks like someone else tested it, in German though: https://www.onli-blogging.de/1392/Ubuntu-14.04-auf-F2FS.html

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that you can read and write to an F2FS partition but it doesn't seem like it's currently possible to boot from or install to one. This may change as F2FS gains popularity and features. For now I would use ext4 for installation and booting, F2FS seems like a reasonable choice for storing a database...